# Change source code in Rstudio but the code is written in C

Tags: r, c, statistics, time-series, rstudio

I working with the ACDm package in Rstudio, which is a very helpful package for my topic. I came across the author's manual and noticed that the LACD1 and LACD2 functions deviates slightly from the original paper:

[image]

The conditional duration ( in the picture as mu_i) enters as a logarithmic value in the equation, which is not according to the original paper assumption.

They should enter in the equation like this:

[image]

The conditional duration (here as psi) enters not as a logarithmic value. The conditional duration is then used to calculate the expected durations as `x_i = exp(psi_i)*randomErrorTerm`

If the conditional duration enters already as a logarithmic value (picture 1) in the formula and it is then used to calculate the expected durations, it looks like this `x_i = exp(log(psi_i)))*randomErrorTerm`, which is not according to the origin paper.

To correct this, I basically have remove a "log" in the source code of the ACDm Package.

The problem is, that that the source code of the LACD1/LACD12 is written in c.

I was wondering if RStudio provides a method to change source code written in c, and use the package with the changed source code for at least the duration of the session?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why it should make a difference whether a term is expressed as _ln µᵢ_ or as _ψᵢ_ when it appears consistently at all places in an equation; in other words, _ψ_ and _ln µ_ are just aliases. And I don't see where `x_i = exp(log(psi_i)))*randomErrorTerm` comes from.

Comment: x_i = exp(log(psi_i)))*randomErrorTerm comes form the the original paper. The randomErrorTerm is just by assumption a random variable (i.e. a weibull distributed variable). I also ask myself if it really makes a difference whether psi enters in the equation as ln(psi) as long it is consistently.  I came up with my conclusion that it makes  a difference because the hole scheme of the calculation is an autoregressiv scheme i.e. x_i = exp(log(psi_i)))*randomErrorTerm ist not equal to x_i = exp((psi_i)))*randomErrorTerm and then x_i is used to calculate the consecutive psi (psi_(i+1)).

Comment: The model original model stems form  to Luc Bauwesen and Giot [200] or Luc Bauwens et al. [2008]

Comment: And psi and mu are not aliases they are basically two different letters explaining the same namely the conditional duration of the model. The difference is, that one is logarithm value  and the other not. Which means in the logarithm model the esitmated duration is calculated like this; x_i = exp(log(mu_i)))*randomErrorTerm

Comment: I don't feel competent to judge the mathematical aspect of the question - perhaps it is advisable to clarify this at math.stackexchange.com first. Regarding your question here - I don't think that RStudio contains a C compiler, which would be necessary _to change_ _code written in c_.

Comment: okay.. But is it possible to replace a source code written in c with another custom file ? I mean at some point in the R code a function calls getLL.c. Let's supposed I have another C file which has the "corrected" form in it and would be called getLL2.c. Where do I have to deploy the file (environment etc.).

Comment: Can you show or link to this _point in the R code_? I'd be surprised if **uncompiled** C code can be called from R. [Using R — Calling C Code ‘Hello World!’](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1067) may be of interest.